# How do I use Firebase Auth's signinWithFacebook() method

Tags: flutter

The '[firebase_auth](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/firebase_auth)' package for Flutter documents how to signinWithGoogle() and signinAnonymously() and both are working fine.

There is no mention of Facebook in the README but when viewing the code I see that there is a [signinWithFacebook()](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/2cd4885c0fbaac8caac5ae3e51bcb2a09607c1cf/packages/firebase_auth/lib/firebase_auth.dart#L133) method there.

Does anyone know if this is finished implemented and if so how to use it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you need to couple this with [facebook_connect](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_facebook_connect) , and then you can do something like this:

```
onPressed:_singInWithFacebook()

....
Future _singInWithFacebook() async {
  final _facebookConnect = new FacebookConnect(
      appId: '<APP_ID>',
      clientSecret: '<CLIENT_SECRET>');
  FacebookOAuthToken token = await _facebookConnect.login();
  final FirebaseUseruser=await_auth.signInWithFacebook(accessToken:token.access);
  print(user);
```

**This was tested with firebaseAuth version 0.1.2**